Transform all files in a folder using saxon-js command line
With the java version of Saxon I can run the following in a bash script: java -cp "${PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH}"/saxon/saxon-he-11.5.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -t -s:"${SCHEMAS_FOLDER}" -xsl:"${PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH}"/XSLT/index.xsl -o:"${PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH}"/HTML schemasFolder="${SCHEMAS_FOLDER}" and transform all the xml files in a folder.
When I run the following using saxon-js xslt3 -s:"${SCHEMAS_FOLDER}" -xsl:"${PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH}"/XSLT/index.xsl -o:"${PROJECT_FOLDER_PATH}"/HTML schemasFolder="${SCHEMAS_FOLDER}" -t, I get the following error message: "Failed to read XML source input (Failed to read /Users/xxx/Dev/s1000d-schemas-viewer/Data (EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read))".
I am new to saxon-js and node.js and trying to read the documentation but so far haven't seen anything related to this

This feature (processing an entire directory) isn't available on the SaxonJS command line. You're going to have to iterate over the files in your bash script and transform each one individually. The documentation seems clear enough: it says that the value of -s must be an "XML source file".
